# how to make pagination in Table View in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, pagination

I am a beginner, I get 300 data from a server and I store this data in an Array [[String:String]], I don't want all those 300 data displayed in the table view at  once, but I want to display it incrementally, let say 15 data per scroll in table view, after 15 data loaded, the next 15 will be loaded if the user reach the bottom of table view scroll.

I should do this because one of the data is actually an imagePath, so I will download an Image, it will take too much time if I download all 300 image at once.

I have tried, but I can't get what I want. I simplify this case to just using an Array of integer like the code below. could you please help me how to do that? Thanks in advance :)

```
class ViewController2: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!


    var data = [Int]()



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.dataSource = self

        for i in 0...300 {
            data.append(i)
        }

    }


}



extension ViewController2 : UITableViewDataSource {

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {


        return

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: nil)

        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(data[indexPath.row])"

        return cell
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {



    }



}
```

Comment: you can load parts of data (step by step) and load content for each section

Answer (score 0):

I think You have to add a key of "Count" at sever for sending How many row you want in one time, then it handle by sever data query and you can refer this project for swift
https://github.com/MrAlek/PagedArray

Answer (score 0):

You're completely fine and have not a single worry. `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` are already super efficient protocols for these tasks. Let me explain:

No matter if it's 300 or 10 thousand items you're getting from your API, as long as it's only text the latency won't drop (only text responses don't make that big of a footprint in the bandwidth). Why is this? Because `UITableViewDelegate` already organizes the display of them for you. You won't be showing all of your 300 items at once, instead you'll be recycling cells and showing them per demand (as the user scrolls). This is the sole purpose of `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`. Of course, you need to have at least one register cell for that matter and make use of `tableView.dequeueReusableCell` in the mentioned method above.

As for your imagePaths downloads, this is where things get interesting. You can achieve this by many approaches, Apple recently even added a new delegate called `UIPrefetchDataSource` which gives you even more control over what cells would *probably* show when user is scrolling so you can set things up in advance. However, even if you decided to go for a more simplistic method, you'd still need to handle concurrency -users won't just sit still staring at your screen during 30-45seconds waiting for images to show in order to keep scrolling (apps like *Instagram* would be unusable)-. I strongly recommend you to take a look into this awesome [article](https://medium.com/capital-one-developers/boost-smooth-scrolling-with-ios-10-pre-fetching-api-818c25cd9c5d) by [Andrea Prearo](https://twitter.com/andrea_prearo) tackling all these issues.